# Can't run java prorgram with "java" command directly

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

I have compiled the java codes with

```
razrlele@OVO:~/workspace/javastudy/src$ javac Helloworld.java
```

and it turns out no errors or warnings

then I run the program with

```
razrlele@OVO:~/workspace/javastudy/src$ java Helloworld
```

it returns this

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Helloworld
```

I have to input like this

```
razrlele@OVO:~/workspace/javastudy/src$ java -cp ./ Helloworld
```

so that the program will run correctlly.

I am confused about why the "java" command doesn't work.

Here is my /etc/environment

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_11"                    
CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_11                                                                                      
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_11
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java will attempt to use your classpath to locate the class files. Since your classpath is set to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_11`, that's where it looks.

By overriding the classpath with `-cp ./`, you tell it to look in the current directory for its class files.

There are a number of ways to fix this, including changing your classpath environment variable to include `.` or other localised paths as needed. I tend to prefer just setting up an alias (in my `.bashrc` for example) so regular Java programs aren't affected, something like (from memory):

```
alias jhere="java -cp $CLASSPATH:."
```

then I can just use:

```
jhere HelloWorld
```

to test my snippets.

Answer (score 3):

Because `.` isn't in your `CLASSPATH`, first

```
export CLASSPATH="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_11:."
```

then

```
javac Helloworld.java
java Helloworld
```

It's also possible to use `-cp` (which is short for `-classpath`) with `java` at the command line, if you run `java -h` you will see

> ```
> -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
>    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
>               A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
>               and ZIP archives to search for class files.
> ```

Comment: should I add `export CLASSPATH="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_11:."` or replace `CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_11  ` with that?

Comment: The export command will set it once. If you edit your `/etc/environment` it will be set across restarts. Finally, you can use `-cp` or `-classpath` at run-time. Other common solutions are start shell scripts and batch files.

Comment: Sorry about I have to accept the other answer for he has offered a more specific solution, but both of you have excellent answers, so I upvote both while I can only pick one answer as accepted, really appreciate for your answering.